# PFQuery with multiple arrays into UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform, pfquery

This is the function I use to query the database:

```
func loadRestaurantMeals(){
        let mealsQuery = PFQuery(className: "Meals")
        mealsQuery.whereKey("Restaurant", equalTo: selectedRestaurant!)
        mealsQuery.whereKey("MealCategory", equalTo: selectedMenuHeading!)
        mealsQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{ (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil{
                //after successfull fetch
                if let fetchedMeals = objects{
                    print("c")

                    for fetchedMeal in fetchedMeals{
                        print("writing to name")
                        self.restaurantMealsArray.append(fetchedMeal.objectForKey("MealName") as! String)
                        print("writing to description")
                        self.mealsDescriptionArray.append(fetchedMeal.objectForKey("MealDescription") as! String)
                        print("writing to price")
                        self.mealsPriceArray.append(fetchedMeal.objectForKey("MealPrice") as! Double)
                    }

                    //display content
                    print("before reload data")
                    self.mealsTableView.reloadData()
                    print("reload data")
                }
            }else{
                // Log details of the failure
                print("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
```

Here are all the UITableView functions:

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return restaurantMealsArray.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("mealCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        print("a")
        cell.textLabel?.text = restaurantMealsArray[indexPath.row]
        print("b")
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = mealsDescriptionArray[indexPath.row]
        print("c")
        //cell.label
        return cell
    }
```

For some reason, the `reloadData()` is never called. 
The console reports the following error :

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: On which line exactly do you get the exception?

Comment: Did you try to print fetchedMeal? MealName, MealDescription, MealPrice types are not optional.

Comment: This error is only presented once I run the app and enter this specific table viewcontroller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose the trouble is caused by the following line:

```
self.mealsPriceArray.append(fetchedMeal.objectForKey("MealPrice") as! Double)
```

`objectForKey` returns an object but you force-convert to Double which doesn't work. Try this:

```
self.mealsPriceArray.append((fetchedMeal.objectForKey("MealPrice") as! NSNumber).doubleValue)
```

(assuming your `mealsPriceArray` is a `[Double]`)

**Better yet:** Since you never can be sure of the data you get from any external source you should really use `?` instead of `!` for the mealPrice and the other data fields as well:

```
if let mealPrice = fetchedMeal.objectForKey("MealPrice") as? NSNumber {
    self.mealsPriceArray.append(mealPrice.doubleValue)
}
```